# How to attach an object with an image view and get it back on next screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an activity in my app which displays rss feeds and next to each rss feed arrow image is attached.. i want to attach the news object to the arrow so that when it is clicked i can pass that object to the next activity an dislay the details ??

I am new to android any help will be appreciated.

Update :
I have updated my code and now i am using setTag with my image view to attach an object with it ...
but actually first i shall explain what i am doing to display rss news ...

i have a seperate dummy xml layout for a single rss.. i have set id for arrow image (which will navigate o the next activity) in it as iv_arrow_img
i am itterating over the news feeds i get and for each news feed i am adding the dummy view again and again...my question is how will i distinguish between different image arrow's ids .. because for now all are having the same id...
how will i set onclick listeners to them ???

updated :sample code

Iterator itr = data.iterator(); int i =0; while (itr.hasNext()) { NewsPostDTO newspostdto = itr.next();

```
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rl_news_item, null);
    lnContentView.addView(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);


    ivArrowfwd = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrowfwd);

    tvNewsHeading.setText(newspostdto.getFeaturedDesc());
    tvNewsContent.setText(newspostdto.getDate() + " - " + newspostdto.getTitle());

    ivArrowfwd.setTag(newspostdto.getId());
    ivArrowfwd.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            System.out.println("sdfsdf" +ivArrowfwd.getTag());

            return false;

    });
}
```

getTag() is not returnig unique values .. i am geting same value on each news arrow when i click it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign object to any image view you can use `setTag()` method and to retirieve the information on you can use `getTag()` method

### Example

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview001);
        iv.setTag(objectassignedToTheImage);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Object passToIntent =iv.getTag()
            }
        });
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: I have updated my code and now i am using setTag with my image view to attach an object with it ... but actually first i shall explain what i am doing to display rss news ...

i have a seperate dummy xml layout for a single rss.. i have set id for arrow image (which will navigate o the next activity) in it as iv_arrow_img
i am itterating over the news feeds i get and for each news feed i am adding the dummy view again and again...my question is how will i distinguish between different image arrow's ids .. because for now all are having the same id... how will i set onclick listeners to them

Answer (score 2):

Data can be passed between activities by adding it to the Intent object. Please check this question for how to do this:
[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

That said, I'd highly recommend using an MVC pattern.

Comment: I think u idnot understand my question .. i have multiple arrow images on my activity i want to attach each arrow its newsto atow h object attach so that when it is clicked ican get it back that object .. iknow how to pass it to activity... but first i want to get the associated object...

Comment: Yes. I had misunderstood your question. I think Deepak has answered it correctly.